# What to log in Mongodb using RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, rabbitmq

All, I have recently integrated Nodejs with Rabbitmq. Mine is a UI application(ReactJS), which sends Post, patch etc. requests to nodejs.
I want to know if I have integrated nodejs with Rabbitmq, then what should I write onto the rabbitMQ which should be read from the queue itself what should be written to mongoDB